# For what value of $n \in \Bbb N$ the function $f(x)=x^n$ is uniformly continuous in all of the set $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

For what value of $n \in \Bbb N$ the function $f(x)=x^n$ is uniformly continuous in all of the set $\Bbb R$_

I've been trying to work on this problem but I don't really know what to do. 
Can you help me understand this problem?

Comment: "For a function to be uniformly continuous in $\Bbb R$ then its derivative should be bounded in $\Bbb R$." That's false actually.

Comment: Oh yes, I guess I got that wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $n>1.$ Let $\delta > 0.$ Then by the mean value theorem,

$$(x+\delta)^n-x^n = nc^{n-1}\delta,$$

where $c\in (x,x+\delta).$

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your claim about the boundedness of $f'$ is equivalent to the uniform continuity of $f$. However to prove that $x \mapsto x^n$ is not uniformly continuous for $n > 1$, you can use $$\left(p^2+\frac1p\right)^n - p^{2n}= \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac1{p^k} p^{2(n-k)} \ge_{k=1} np^{2n-3} \to_{p\to \infty} \infty $$ For $n = 0$ it is constant so uniform continuous and as @Ian say in the comment it is uniformly continuous for $n= 1$.

---

In the above reasoning, I am using that 
$$
f \text{ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$ $\Leftrightarrow$ for every sequences $(x_n),(y_n)$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n - y_n = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) - f(y_n) = 0$} 
$$

Comment: $x \mapsto x$ is obviously uniformly continuous, so your bound must have some error.

Comment: Yes that's correct ! I edit my answer.

Comment: My point is that your bound *itself* is not saying what you want it to say. It's comparing $(x^2+\epsilon)^n$ with $x^{2n}$. You want to compare $(x+\epsilon)^n$ with $x^n$ instead.

Comment: It is the same thing. no ?

Comment: No, it's not, because you've used a non-uniformly continuous change of variable in switching from $x$ to $x^2$.

Comment: Non I am taking $p \in \mathbb N$ and $x_p = p^2 + \frac1p$, $y_p = p^2$

Comment: I see your point now. But now I see the issue, your problem was just with exponent bookkeeping. It is actually still wrong: the leading order term is proportional to $p^{2n-3}$ for fixed $n$, which is growing for integer $n>1$. It is *decaying* for $n=1$ which is to be expected.

Comment: Now it is correct ?

Comment: Now it's right.